# How to declare a pointer to a variable as a parameter of a function in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, declaration, function-parameter

I have a function that takes a `const D3DVECTOR3 *pos`, but I have no reason to declare this beforehand.  The most logical solution to me was using new:

```
Function(
    //other parameters,
    new D3DXVECTOR3(x, y, 0));
```

but I don't know how I would go about `deleting` it, beign intitialized in a function.  My next thought was to use the `&` operator, like so:

```
Function(
    //other parameters,
    &D3DVECTOR3(x, y, 0));
```

but I don't know if this is a valid way to go about doing this.  (It doesn't get an error, but there are a lot of things that don't give errors that aren't necassarily good).  So should I use `new`, `&`, or some other technique I'm overlooking?

Comment: If you don't get an error for `int *x; x = 50;` then I have no idea what kind if compiler you are using. It is certainly not a C++ compiler...

Comment: @Andrey - Yeah, I see now; I was trying to give an example of seomthing that could be done without errors but ins't necassarily good practice.  I'm changing it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to directly invoke the address-of operator to the temporary (MSVC will tell you that this is not Standard C++ at higher warning levels, too). Except you may do

```
Function(
//other parameters,
&(D3DXVECTOR3 const&)D3DXVECTOR3(x, y, 0));
```

But this is disgusting. Just declare a local variable and pass its address.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the difference between `&(D3DXVECTOR3 const&)D3DXVECTOR3(x, y, 0)` and `&D3DVECTOR3(x, y, 0)`?

Comment: @Keand64, You cannot take the address of the temporary. But once you bind the temporary to a reference, the reference will guarantee the `&` that the operand has an address (it can copy the temporary to some location), and the operation will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to not instantiate the object before the function call then delete it afterwards. Also worth noting,

```
Function(
//other parameters,
new D3DXVECTOR3(x, y, 0));
```

I think this will result in a memory leak if Function does not return a pointer or deposit it into some kind of memory pool. Hope this helps.